# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock game logic outputting wrong winners occasionally and I can't tell why

Tags: javascript

I am a newby at JavaScript. I just can't figure why this is giving the wrong winner sometimes. It said Rock wins when the user chose Rock and the computer chose Paper. Several other combinations have come out wrong too. Can anyone tell where I went wrong? Thanks!

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.21) {
    computerChoice = "Rock";
} else if(computerChoice > 0.20 && computerChoice < 0.41) {
    computerChoice = "Paper";
} else if(computerChoice >0.40 && computerChoice < 0.61) {
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
} else if(computerChoice > 0.60 && computerChoice < 0.81) {
    computerChoice = "Lizard";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Spock";
}
console.log("The player chooses: " + userChoice);
console.log("The computer chooses: " + computerChoice);
function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        console.log("The result is a tie!");
    } else if(choice1 === "Rock") {
        if(choice2 === "Scissors" || "Lizard") {
            console.log("Rock wins!");
        } else if(choice2 === "Paper") {
            console.log("Paper wins!"); 
        } else {
            console.log("Spock wins");
        }
    } else if(choice1 === "Paper") {
        if(choice2 === "Rock" || "Spock") {
            console.log("Paper wins!");
        } else if(choice2 === "Scissors") {
            console.log("Scissors wins!");
        } else {
            console.log("Lizard wins!");
        }
    } else if(choice1 === "Scissors") {
        if(choice2 === "Paper" || "Lizard") {
            console.log("Scissors wins!");
        } else if(choice2 === "Rock") {
            console.log("Rock wins!");
        } else {
            console.log("Spock wins!");
        }
    } else if(choice1 === "Lizard") {
        if(choice2 === "Paper" || "Spock") {
            console.log("Lizard wins!");
        } else if(choice2 === "Rock") {
            console.log("Rock wins!");
        } else {
            console.log("Spock wins!");
        }
    } else if(choice1 === "Spock") {
        if(choice2 === "Rock" || "Scissors") {
            console.log("Spock wins!");
        } else if(choice2 === "Paper") {
            console.log("Paper wins!");
        } else {
            console.log("Lizard wins!");
        }
    }
}
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made the same mistake several times. To take the first one as an example. This:

> ```
> if(choice2 === "Scissors" || "Lizard") {
> ```

… means:

IF

- choice2 === "Scissors" is a true value *or*
- "Lizard" is a true value

… and "Lizard" will *always* be a true value.

You need to fully describe the condition:

```
choice2 === "Scissors" || choice2 === "Lizard"
```

… or use an array

```
["Scissors", "Lizard"].indexOf(choice2) > -1
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense!